# Using a Lambda as a Function replacement

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm trying to figure out a way to pass a lambda as a function replacement.

Normally, I'd do this:

```
InputExampleToMe( ... );

static int ExampleFunction( void *one, int two, int three, void *four )
{
    static_cast< std::string * >( four )->append( static_cast< char * >( one ), two * three );
    return two * three;
};

/* ... */

int main( )
{
    InputExampleToMe( ExampleFunction );
}
```

I'm trying to see if there's a way to declare a static lambda to pass as a parameter. Something like this:

```
InputExampleToMe( ... );

/* ... */

int main( )
{
    InputExampleToMe( [ ]( void *one, int two, int three, void *four )-> static int{ static_cast< std::string * >( four )->append( static_cast< char * >( one ), two * three ); return two * three; }; );
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the context of your code, but `std::string*` is almost certainly not good C++. You may make `InputExampleToMe` a *function-template* to take any type. If you are looking for a particular functor signature, non-capturing lambdas can implicitly decompose to function pointers

Comment: It's not my code example, it's OpenSSL. I need to pass one of their functions to one of their other functions :P I only use it once and don't touch it again, and want to leave all the ugly code of OpenSSL with the OpenSSL portion of my project. Creating a lambda would be best if possible

Answer (score 0):

A stateless lambda is convertible to a function pointer with the same signature.

```
#include <string>

void InputExampleToMe(int (*pf)(void*, int, int, void*));

auto ExampleFunction = []( void *one, int two, int three, void *four ) -> int
{
    static_cast< std::string * >( four )->append( static_cast< char * >( one ), two * three );
    return two * three;
};

/* ... */

int main( )
{
    InputExampleToMe( ExampleFunction );
}
```

Caveat: Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: Would this function as the original, statically? I don't see any identifiers to note that ExampleFunction is static.

Comment: @jijemi you could declare ExampleFunction static by all means, or declare it in an anonymous namespace (which would achieve the same thing). It's just an object.